# python - TypeError: "quoting" must be an integer

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to define a new format:

```
import csv 
f = open("file.csv")
reader = csv.reader(f)

class my_dialect(csv.Dialect):
     lineterminator = '\n'
     delimiter: ';'
     quotechar: '"'

reader = csv.reader(f, dialect=my_dialect)
```

Output:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-121-0a8ad3677c01> in <module>()
----> 1 reader = csv.reader(f, dialect=my_dialect)

TypeError: "quoting" must be an integer
```

From documentation:

> Dialect.quoting
>       Controls when quotes should be generated by the writer and recognised by the reader. It can take on any of the QUOTE_* constants
>   (see section Module Contents) and defaults to QUOTE_MINIMAL.

What does that mean?

Comment: That isn't even valid Python.

Comment: Not sure why this is tagged pandas if you're just using `csv`.

Comment: You need to import and use a constant value of `QUOTE_MINIMAL`, or other

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, there are syntax errors with your code that are unrelated to your original question, so please make sure those are taken care of (assignment operator is "=", not ":"). If you add in quoting to your class, it should fix the error you are getting. Your code could look something like this --

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import csv 
f = open("file.csv")
reader = csv.reader(f)

class my_dialect(csv.Dialect):
    lineterminator = '\n'
    delimiter= ';'
    quotechar= '"'
    quoting = csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL

reader = csv.reader(f, dialect=my_dialect)
```

Comment: what kind of syntax errors? where? saying theres some errors fix them will not help OP. Explain if you can how to fix them

Comment: The code added above addresses the syntax issues, but I have added in an edit to my post to help explain what I was referring to.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can't believe I didn't realize I was using colons instead of '='...

Comment: I don't understand why omitting the quoting option altogether returns this error if it defaults to csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL ?

Comment: The reason you get the error when omitting "quoting" from your class, is because you are passing your class as the the dialect when calling csv.reader. In this situation, dialect looks to your class for the arguments and won't like if it can't find one or more arguments. If on the other hand, you did something like csv.reader(f, lineterminator='\n', delimiter=';', quotechar='"'), you would not run into the same error because in this case, "quoting" as an arg defaults to csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL. Refer to documentation of the reader function in csv to see how the functions/constructors are set up.